Is there a known issue causing Ubuntu 24.04 File Splice Errors?
I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 24.04 that is unable to copy data from USB drives.  I have been able to reproduce this on multiple computers and multiple drives.
The error in the GUI is:  Error splicing file: Input/output error
In dmesg there are many errors like this:
[ 2512.010184] I/O error, dev sde, sector 4019644311 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 35 prio class 0
[ 2512.010201] I/O error, dev sde, sector 4019644311 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 4 prio class 0
[ 2512.010285] I/O error, dev sde, sector 2036558951 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 2512.010294] I/O error, dev sde, sector 2036558951 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 2512.010651] I/O error, dev sde, sector 2036929895 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x84700 phys_seg 128 prio class 0
[ 2512.010658] I/O error, dev sde, sector 2036930919 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x84700 phys_seg 128 prio class 0
[ 2512.010662] I/O error, dev sde, sector 2036931943 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x84700 phys_seg 128 prio class 0


[ 2512.010666] I/O error, dev sde, sector 2036932967 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x84700 phys_seg 128 prio class 0
[ 2512.010669] I/O error, dev sde, sector 2036933991 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x84700 phys_seg 128 prio class 0
[ 2512.010672] I/O error, dev sde, sector 2036935015 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 28 prio class 0

The OS version is Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I have tried a Seagate 5 TB external USB drive and an Acasis 4TB NVME USB-C drive.  I have plugged then into a high speed front panel 5.25 insert connected to the USB 3.2 Gen 2 Type-C Front Panel Connector, to the USB 3.2 Gen 1 Type-C Front Panel Connector, and to the back panel USB3 and USB-C connectors.  Both drives have been tested against every possible USB port on the system.
I have a second dual boot 24.04 / 22.04.6 machine and the 22.04 installation can read and write the same drives with no issues. The 24.04 installation can't read them.
I have two tests for each drive.  I try to copy a 400 GB Linux VM and a 1.2 tb Ubuntu repo.  On 24.04 they fail 100% of the time.  On 22.04 they succeed 100% of the time.
The tests that fail don't do so instantly.  They each get to an unremarkable smallish file and fail.  It isn't the same file each time.  Both fail in under a minute.
The drives are formatted as XFS V5 volumes.
xfs_db output:
versionnum [0xb4a5+0x18a] = V5,NLINK,DIRV2,ALIGN,LOGV2,EXTFLG,MOREBITS,ATTR2,LAZYSBCOUNT,PROJID32BIT,CRC,FTYPE,FINOBT,SPARSE_INODES,REFLINK

All the systems have been patched today.
FWIW, Linux Mint 22 is doing the same thing.
Are there any other places I should be looking?

dmesg is an obsolete, incomplete, method of querying system events. Use sudo journalctl  -b 0 /dev/sde to see more. Read man journalctl - it's more complex, but much more powerful than dmesg.
